# Get minutes since last inserted row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to prevent spamming on my commenting system, and to stop users posting more than one comment too quickly, and want a 5-minutes delay between comment posts. When a user posts a message, I want to run a quick query which finds out how many minutes have passed since the users last post, on a particular article.

This is my table data:

[blog_comments]

```
comment_id | article_id | commenter_id | comment           | posted
-----------|------------|--------------|-------------------|---------------------
1          | 1023       | 2322         | blah blah blah    | 2013-08-29 17:27:03
```

I need to find out how many minutes difference there is between (now and posted) but using UTC_TIMESTAMP().

I'm looking at DATEDIFF AND TIMEDIFF but having troubles working it out, because TIMEDIFF requires times not dates, and DATEDIFF returns in days.

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), posted)
FROM blog_comments
WHERE article_id = 1023 AND commenter_id = 2322
```

But how do I get minutes? I want this so I can report back to the user, who just posted a comment, to wait another 'X' minutes/seconds until posting again. Minutes and seconds would be a huge bonus.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Aside: It is probably quicker to do the computing without SQL. Grab the timestamp and compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,posted,Now()) AS minutes_since_post
FROM blog_comments
WHERE article_id = 1023 AND commenter_id = 2322
```

Answer (score 0):

`DATEDIFF` will return the difference in days. Try the `TIMEDIFF` function instead.